# замена символа по позиции в shell

Tags: linux, shell

Строка, в которой известна длина. Как заменить символы на определенных позициях, при этом не меняя такие же встречающиеся символы в этой строке на других позициях?
То есть в `aabbсс` заменить третью слева `b` и последнюю `c` на другие нужные буквы или цифры > `aa4bcd` ? если можно, то безусловную замену заменяемого символа - то есть не прописывать отдельно какой символ меняем, меняем любой, но на определенной позиции.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469977/replace-particular-string-at-fixed-position-using-sed

Comment: средствами posix-совместимой оболочки это невозможно сделать. требуется либо расширенная функциональность (имеется, например, в программах *bash/zsh*), либо использование дополнительных программ (*cut/sed/awk* и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: А на cut/sed/awk ? И кстати, какая из этих команд будет более быстрая?

Comment: *А на cut/sed/awk ?* — а это уже совсем **другие** программы, к вашему вопросу отношения не имеющие.

Comment: по поводу невозможности я, пожалуй, перегнул палку. реализовать-то, конечно, можно. ведь posix-совместимая оболочка — это вполне себе [тьюринг-полный язык программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83).

Comment: думаю сut/sed/awk менял вполне устроит. этот вопрос тогда можно закрыть и переношу его в новый https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/856208/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-cut-sed-awk

Answer (score 0):

раз поставлены столь жёсткие ограничения — использовать только возможности программы-оболочки, да ещё и в самом урезанном виде — posix-совместимой, то для замены, например, третьего символа на указанный, действовать надо как и в любом другом языке программирования:

1. извлечь из строки первые два символа:

   ```
   ${var%${var#??}}
   ```
2. добавить символ-замену:

   ```
   $zamena
   ```
3. добавить символы исходной строки, начиная с четвёртого:

   ```
   ${var#???}
   ```

итого:

```
var=${var%${var#??}}$zamena${var#???}
```