# замена символа по позиции ( cut/sed/awk)

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Строка, в которой известна длина. Как заменить символы на определенных позициях, при этом не меняя такие же встречающиеся символы в этой строке на других позициях?

То есть в `aabbсс` заменить третью слева `b` и последнюю `c` на другие нужные буквы или цифры > `aa4bcd`? Если можно, то безусловную замену заменяемого символа - то есть не прописывать отдельно какой символ меняем, меняем любой, но на определенной позиции.

Comment: Я в прошлом вашем вопроседал ссылку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469977/replace-particular-string-at-fixed-position-using-sed  там делают именно это, заменяют символы в 11 позиции. только еще доп. условия стоят, вроде определенных символов после. вам надо просто поправить регулярку на нужные вам символы и позиции

Comment: Mike, да, я видел, спасибо. Пока не приспособил синтаксис именно к своей ситуации, мне, как чайнику все это тяжело дается(

Comment: да буквально https://regex101.com/r/ONMog9/1 только в строке подстановки вместо `$1 $2` используются `\1 \2`

Comment: у меня получается только добавить после определенной позиции, а не заменить. например `echo aabbсс | sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)/\14/'` - где после третьего символа от начала b вставляется 4 `aab4bсс`, а надо бы вместо. что не так?

Comment: `\1` подставляет целиком содержимое скобок, а все, что никак не указано остается на месте. Надо указать что есть заменяемый символ за пределами скобок. `sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)./\14/'`. Ну или вместо точки указать явно `b` если надо заменять строго ее, а не любой символ

Comment: только вот если `sed 's/^\(.\{3\}\)./\14/'` - то меняется четвертый символ, а не третий, так и должно быть? по сути глобально не влияет, можно указывать и предыдущую позицию чтобы добиться нужного, но это нормально? или что-то все же не так с синтаксисом? и как правильно составить одной командой, когда несколько вхождений в строке, чтобы не городить sed дважды подряд?

Comment: да, мы же явно выделили первые 3 символа и их скопировали и после них один заменили. так что для замены 3-его надо копировать только 2. если позиция второго вхождения то же фиксирована то просто явно выделяете следующую часть для копирования, что то вроде `sed 's/^\(..\).\(.\{5\}\)./\14\2X/'` если строка переменной длины то в скобках захватить необределенную длину с помощью `.*` потом за рамками скобок заменяемый символ и знак `$` что бы указать, что за ним уже конец строки

Comment: я видоизменил на более лаконичный для меня, но объединить пока получилось только так, решение моего вопроса: `sed -E -e 's/^(.{2})./\14/' -e 's/^(.{5})./\1d/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую ответить так:

```
echo aabbсс | sed -E 's/^(.{2})(.)/\14/;s/.$/d/'
```

первый шаблон:

- ^(.{2}) - ищем любые 2 символа в начале строки и сохраняем результат
  в \1
- (.) - находим любой 1 символ после предыдущего шаблона и
  сохраняем результат в \2

собираем строку

- \1 - вставляем найденные символы,
- 4 - заменяем то что нашли в \2 на символ - 4, остальная строка не меняется.

То что идет после символа ; это втрой шаблон:

- .$ - последний символ сохраняем в \1

собираем строку

- d - тот символ который нашли в конце строки меняем на символ d

В итоге заменили точно 3 и последний символ в строке, правда это как-то явно можно объденить в один шаблон, но это уже оптимизация

Answer (score 3):

```
echo aabbсс | awk '{print gensub(".","4",3)}'
```

. - regexp (Любой символ)
4 - Символ на который меняем
3 - Позиция символа для замены